# Loop through several ranges with same code

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA and I would like to ask for help. 
I want to clear the code as I am using same loop code for several ranges.

I have form, where I have like 10 tables (located in 2 columns x 5 below). Each table can contains up to 5 lines, and have 4 columns (5x4).

I want to import inputs from the tables in new sheet via vba. 
So I create a loop for certain ranges. The ranges are (line 54:58, 65:69, 76:80, 87:91, 98:102), columns (3-6) & (9-12) 
I do not want to import blanks fields, therefore there is a condition if.

Is there a way how to simplified the code, that I do not have to loop each range? something like "loop these ranges" and having there the code only once?

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim p As Long, i As Long
Dim lastrowPest As Long, lastrowField As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSource = wb.Sheets("Field entry - plan")
Set wsTarget = wb.Sheets("List3")


lastrowField = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 20).End(xlUp).row

For p = 54 To 58

    For i = 3 To lastrowField

        If wsSource.Cells(p, 4) <> "" Then

        lastrowPest = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 24).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

        wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 20), wsSource.Cells(i, 20)).copy
        wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 24), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 24)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 34), wsSource.Cells(i, 34)).copy
        wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 30), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 30)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(p, 3), wsSource.Cells(p, 6)).copy
        wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 26), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 28)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        End If

        If wsSource.Cells(p, 10) <> "" Then

        lastrowPest = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 24).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

        wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 20), wsSource.Cells(i, 20)).copy
        wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 24), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 24)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 34), wsSource.Cells(i, 34)).copy
        wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 30), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 30)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(p, 9), wsSource.Cells(p, 12)).copy
        wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 26), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 28)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        End If
    Next i

Next p


For p = 65 To 69

    For i = 3 To lastrowField

        If wsSource.Cells(p, 4) <> "" Then

        lastrowPest = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 24).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

        wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 20), wsSource.Cells(i, 20)).copy
        wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 24), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 24)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 34), wsSource.Cells(i, 34)).copy
        wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 30), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 30)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(p, 3), wsSource.Cells(p, 6)).copy
        wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 26), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 28)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        End If

        If wsSource.Cells(p, 10) <> "" Then

        lastrowPest = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 24).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

        wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 20), wsSource.Cells(i, 20)).copy
        wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 24), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 24)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 34), wsSource.Cells(i, 34)).copy
        wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 30), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 30)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(p, 9), wsSource.Cells(p, 12)).copy
        wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 26), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 28)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        End If
    Next i

Next p
```

Comment: You could put your ranges (or row/column numbers into an array) and loop through the array. Must admit I don't understand why you are copying column 20, 34 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the repetitive code in a different procedure and call it with arguments like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim FirstRows(1 To 2) As Long
    FirstRows(1) = 54
    FirstRows(2) = 65
    Dim LastRows(1 To 2) As Long
    LastRows(1) = 58
    LastRows(2) = 69

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(FirstRows) To UBound(FirstRows)
        CopyPaste FirstRows(i), LastRows(i)
    Next i

End Sub
Private Sub CopyPaste(FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long)


    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim p As Long, i As Long
    Dim lastrowPest As Long, lastrowField As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Sheets("Field entry - plan")
    Set wsTarget = wb.Sheets("List3")


    lastrowField = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 20).End(xlUp).Row


    For p = FirstRow To LastRow

        For i = 3 To lastrowField

            If wsSource.Cells(p, 4) <> "" Then

            lastrowPest = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 24).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 20), wsSource.Cells(i, 20)).Copy
            wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 24), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 24)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 34), wsSource.Cells(i, 34)).Copy
            wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 30), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 30)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(p, 3), wsSource.Cells(p, 6)).Copy
            wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 26), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 28)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            End If

            If wsSource.Cells(p, 10) <> "" Then

            lastrowPest = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 24).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 20), wsSource.Cells(i, 20)).Copy
            wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 24), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 24)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 34), wsSource.Cells(i, 34)).Copy
            wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 30), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 30)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(p, 9), wsSource.Cells(p, 12)).Copy
            wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 26), wsTarget.Cells(lastrowPest, 28)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            End If
        Next i

    Next p

End Sub
```

You can make larger your arrays on the `Test` procedure by changing the `1 to 2`to `1 to whatever number` and suit it to your needs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for help. But I am having an issue with `CopyPaste` - error - Sub or function not defined - in the procedure `Test`.  Should I somehow define CopyPaste?

Comment: @MagicQ `CopyPaste` is the sub below the `Test` one, you need to copy the whole code.